# Feeds XPath parser - setting the created date of a node

Tags: importing-exporting, feeds

I'm importing a date field in the format:

dd/mm/yyyy

I want to set this as the created date for the node I'm creating/updating.

I've tried the Feeds tamper module but the date function seem to convert between a string and a Unix timestamp, which doesn't seem to work anyway.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the hook_feeds_presave in a custom module :

```
function mymodule_feeds_presave(FeedsSource $source, $entity, $item, $entity_id) {
  $your_import_date = explode('/', $item['your_import_date']);
  $your_import_date_formated = $your_import_date[2] . '-' . $your_import_date[1] . '-' . $your_import_date[0] . ' 00:00:00';
  $item['your_import_date'] = strtotime($your_import_date_formated);
  $entity->created = $item['your_import_date'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much pbonnefoi. Just tried this and it worked perfectly.